# Cassandra range query on clustering key

Tags: time, cassandra, range, intervals

Let's say I have this table: `Table1(PartKey, Cluster_Time DESC)` with following tuples:

```
(p1   ,   6.0)
(p1   ,   5.3)
(p1   ,   4.1)
(p1   ,   3.3)
(p1   ,   2.3)
(p1   ,   1.2)
(p1   ,   0.1)
```

Now suppose I make this query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE PartKey = "p1" AND Cluster_Time >= 2.0 AND Cluter_time <=4.0;
```

What I would like to understand is the following.

Does Cassandra:

1) start to scan  partition p1 from the beginning and stops after reaching tuple (p1,2)

OR

2) it has a mechanism to start the scan directly at circa time 4.1?

If such a mechanism is not available, would an index be appropriate for this range query?

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your key is `PRIMARY KEY (PartKey, Cluster_Time)`. Providing your actual schema would help.

Partition `p1` on disk will have all the rows for it in clustering order. The read will use the index component of the sstable which has a marker every 64kb (default) of clustering keys to get as close as it can to `Cluster_Time = 2.0`, skip rows until it reaches it then just continue reading and returning rows until `Cluster_Time <= 4.0`

Comment: Perfect! Yes, indeed that was my schema. Thanks.
PS. What would then the difference in this scenario be if I had DESC? The same reasoning you just did easily apply again, so I am a bit confused.

Comment: Since you have it bound in both min and max it will just change the order you get the rows back.